How can I make Axios globally available in a Vue 3 application using the Composition API with TypeScript?
I've tried using provide/inject:
plugins/axios.ts:
import axios from 'axios'
import type { AxiosInstance } from 'axios'
import type { App } from 'vue'

export default {
    install: (app: App, baseUrl: string) => {
        const axiosInstance: AxiosInstance = axios.create({ baseURL: baseUrl })
        axiosInstance.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        app.provide('axios', axiosInstance)
    }
}

plugins/index.ts
import router from '@/router'
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { axios } from '@/plugins/axios'
import type { App } from 'vue'

export function registerPlugins(app: App) {
    const pinia = createPinia()
    app.use(pinia).use(router)
    axios.install(app, 'http://localhost:4000')
}

main.ts
import App from '@/App.vue'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { registerPlugins } from '@/plugins'

const app = createApp(App)
registerPlugins(app)
app.mount('#app')

Now, attempt to use it in stores/someStore.ts (this is psuedo-code):
import { inject } from 'vue'
import type { AxiosInstance } from 'axios'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useSomeStore = defineStore('SomeStore', () => {
    const axios = inject<AxiosInstance>('axios')

    const getSomeWidgets = async () => {
        return await axios.get('/widgets')
    }

    return { getSomeWidgets }
})

This results in a warning when the store is loaded:
[Vue warn]: injection "axios" not found.

and an eventual "undefined" error when the store method is actually called.
If I attempt to use globalProperties in my axios.ts plugin, like this:
app.config.globalProperties.$axios = axiosInstance

I don't understand how I can access it in stores/components, because this is not available in the Composition API.
// Does not even compile because `this` is undefined
return await this.$axios.get('/widgets')

I've asked AI, Googled everything, paid for tutorials, and still can't find a definitive, simple answer to this question. Can someone please show me how I can make Axios available globally in the Vue 3 Composition API with TypeScript?
EDIT: Complete solution below
In the interest of helping Google find results that I could not, here is the solution I rested on after @Estus Flask's help:
Create a module that constructs the Axios object, put it wherever, I left it in my plugins folder:
import axios from 'axios'

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_HOST}:${import.meta.env.VITE_API_PORT}`,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
})

// set up interceptors or whatever else you need on the Axios instance

export default axiosInstance

Then, create a composable for using Axios in components and/or stores. I chose to call mine "ApiStore" and put it in my stores folder. The API I'm calling is GraphQL, so I can actually do some helpful stuff in here:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axiosHttp from '@/plugins/axiosHttp'

export const useApiStore = defineStore('ApiStore', () => {
    const query = async (name: string, parameters: Record<string, any>, resultSelector: string) => {
        const response = await axiosHttp.post('', {
            query: `{
                ${name}(
                    ${Object.entries(parameters)
                        .map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`)
                        .join(', ')}) {
                            ${resultSelector}
                        }
                    }`
        })
        return response.data.data[name]
    }

    return { query }
})

I can then use this in my other stores like this:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { useApiStore } from '@/stores/apiStore'

export const useWidgetStore = defineStore('WidgetStore', () => {
    const apiStore = useApiStore()
    // state, getters, etc.

    async function getWidgets(categoryId) {
        return await apiStore.query('widgets', { category: categoryId }, `id, name, creationTime`)
    }

    return { getWidgets } 
})


The use of inject is limited to components because provide/inject relies on component hierarchy, while Pinia stores don't have this restriction, so it's incorrect to use it there.
Unless there are some specific requirements to contain Axios instance within Vue app instance (some multi-app build, SSR setup, concurrently running automated tests, etc), there is no need to make it more complicated.
It's as simple as creating a singleton in a module:
export default axios.create(...)

There's nothing wrong with importing it directly through the app where it's used. But it can be wrapped with a composable to use in components for more flexibility:
import myAxios from '@/my-axios';

export default function useMyAxios() {
  return myAxios;
}

The composable is of no practical importance at the moment, but will save from refactoring in case the mentioned specific requirements appear.

So you would suggest making a separate module that constructs Axios and then directly importing that module wherever needed? Does Node/Vue then understand to reuse that object when I reference it through my store modules? E.g., I have @/plugins/axios.ts that creates Axios, sets up interceptors and headers, etc. Then, I could have a utility composable for useAxios. Then, each store that needs HTTP access could simply import the useAxios module?

Yes. Modules are executed once by specification, and exported object is a singleton, there's no additional "understanding" is needed from Node. Then the opposite problem could happen, axios instance could be used for multiple users on server side when defined this way, so storing user-specific data in it would be bad idea, e.g. setting defaults.headers.common,Authorization instead of handling Authorization  header in an interceptor. Just don't do something like that with the instances that exist outside the app

Great, that's excellent information, thank you! That confirms my approach of setting auth headers in an interceptor.

While I still want to learn if there's a way to make Axios globally available, I just found a work-around for this using a Pinia store. This might even be the "right" way to do this.

Remove any Axios plugin and global registration attempts during the application load.

Define a store for the Axios instance, I called mine axiosStore.ts. Use it to construct the Axios instance and set any defaults, like baseURL, any headers, and any interceptors:
import axios from 'axios'
import type { AxiosInstance } from 'axios'
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useAxiosStore = defineStore('AxiosStore', () => {
    const axiosInstance = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://put-this-in-your-env-file',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })
    // put your interceptors and whatever else here
    const http = ref<AxiosInstance>(axiosInstance)
    return { http }
})


Import and use the axiosStore in other stores or wherever you need HTTP access, for example:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { useAxiosStore } from '@/stores/axiosStore'

export const useWidgetStore = defineStore('WidgetStore', () => {
    const { http } = useAxiosStore()
    const getWidgets = async () => {
        return await http.get('/widgets')
    }
    return { getWidgets }
})



Using Vue Dev Tools in Chrome, I can see that the AxiosStore is loaded once and the HTTP call works as expected.

It can be done this way. Notice that accidental ref() may break objects that weren't designed to be reactive, it causes more harm than good. Should likely be  ref(markRaw(axiosInstance)) if you should use useAxiosStore, though there aren't many real uses for it
